# btn-group dropdown does not work, but nav-item dropdown does in Angular with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-5

Would somebody know why the btn-group dropdown does not work and the nav-item dropdown does?

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="btn-group dropdown">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                      Action
                                    </button>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown03" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown03">
                                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                  </li>
                            </div>
```

here you find the styles and scripts from angular.json and you find the dependencies from package.json

```
 "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            ]


"dependencies": {
    ...
    "@angular/forms": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~12.1.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^10.0.0",
    "boostrap": "^2.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
```

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` and `angular.json` file?

Comment: @robert What part do you need from the angular.json and package.json, because I can not add so much code in my post. It gives an error.

Comment: from `package.json` the parts with your `dependencies`, and from `angular.json` the parts where you setup `styles` and `scripts`

Comment: In your html change `data-toggle` to `data-bs-toggle` and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Bootstrap 5 `data-` attributes changed to `data-bs-`